# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource error, appeared in LogCat

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm developing one Android app, in that I'm asking for USER_ID & PASSWORD to user after that want to authenticate that user, for that I have written one php script [I'm using MySQL database (**WAMP Server**)] but don't know why, I'm getting the following error-

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\authenticate_user.php on line *35*

One more thing I would like to mention here is: I'm passing/entering correct USERNAME & PASSWORD (which is exist in database) but still it is giving me the following message

> Not a valid user (Not Found)

for better understanding, please see the code for `authenticate_user.php` and LogCat text given below.

**authenticate_user.php**:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will authenticate the user
 * User_ID & Password are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{

     $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
     $password= $_POST['password'];
     echo "Inside PHP Script" . PHP_EOL;
     echo $user_id . PHP_EOL;
     echo $password . PHP_EOL;

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    // mysql checking if user exist.
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_user_master WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND password = '".$password."'");

    if (!empty($result)) 
    {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
      {           

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Dnyanesh";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
    else 
     {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Not a valid user (Not Found)";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Not a valid user (Empty result)";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} 
else 
{
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Following is my LogCat:

**Note:** Here 123, 123 is my USER_ID & PASSWORD resp. and which is exist in the database

```
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): *****register response ******: Inside PHP Script

07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): 123

07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): 123

07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): <br />
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\authenticate_user.php on line <i>35</i></th></tr>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>138656</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_connect\authenticate_user.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\authenticate_user.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0200</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>161512</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-num-rows' target='_new'>mysql_num_rows</a>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_connect\authenticate_user.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\authenticate_user.php<b>:</b>35</td></tr>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): </table></font>
07-03 07:12:51.514: V/SubWay(1333): {"success":0,"message":"Not a valid user (Not Found)"}
```

Please help. Thank You!

Comment: The problem lies on `authenticate_user.php`, instead of your Android App. You shouldn't post everything here and yell for help. Also, use standard English please.

Comment: i think mysqli use mysqli_num_rows not mysql_num_rows function i.e your connection established with mysqli so expects parameter 1 to be resource is only for mysqli_num_rows..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are mixing mysql with mysqli .

change this

```
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

to

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```